# Incorrect version used when running Python in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to use 3.8 instead of Python 3.10 in Google Colab, so I am switching versions
However, the version from the command line and the actual script execution are different.
How can I use 3.8 in my scripts?

```
# Change Python 3.10 to 3.8
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
!sudo apt-get install python3-pip

# Check version using command
!python --version # -> Python 3.8.10

# Check version using script
from platform import python_version
print(python_version()) # -> 3.10.11
```

I tried new runtime. but not worked.